# Filter objects based on token expiry date and user date_joined using Q and "gt" Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to delete users that haven't activated their accounts when the activation token have expired, activation token expires after 30 minutes.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Now


def delete_unactivated_users():
    User = get_user_model()
    expiry = User.date_joined + timedelta(seconds=1800)
    unactivated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(Now()__gt=expiry) & (Q(is_active = False)))

    for user in unactivated_users:
        user.delete()
        print('<<<User Deleted>>>')
        user.save
```

I am getting a syntax error on line 5 of the code, I tried using

```
unactivated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(expiry__lt=Now()) & (Q(is_active=False)))
```

but it didn't result in the same meaning. The problem seems to be the placing of `Now()` and `expiry` on line 5

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to delete inactive users, more specifically those which have `is_active=False` and `date_joined + 30 minutes is less than Now()`. If that's true here is how you can do that.

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def delete_inactive_users():
    User = get_user_model()

    inactive_users = User.objects.filter(
        date_joined__lt=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(seconds=1800), 
        is_active=False,
    )

    # you can delete all the records by once
    inactive_users.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full error I can't be certain, but there are definitely a few things wrong:

You don't need to save the user after deleting it (in fact you won't be able to as it won't exist) - you can also delete the whole list at once.

You don't need `Q`

The `Now` you are importing isn't correct

This should work:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def delete_unactivated_users(expiry_time):
    User = get_user_model()
    expiry = User.date_joined + timedelta(seconds=1800)
    unactivated_users = User.objects.filter(expiry__lt=now(), is_active = False)

    unactivated_users.delete()
```